# I don't see my Ubuntu's wallpaper

Tags: desktop-background

I can't see my wallpaper I updated Nautillus and BAM! I change it alot of times and Still can't see it, everything works correctly only this bothers me a little please help (Sorry about my englis I'm a spanish speaker)

Comment: This is how it see https://fbcdn-sphotos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/936748_374123526041886_1636168557_n.jpg

Answer (score 0):

### Ubuntu 13.04 Wallpapers

```
 sudo apt-get install ubuntu-wallpapers-raring
```

System Settings > Appearance > Wallpapers

[image]

[image]

[image]